# How do I sequentially select parts of an expression in Vim?

Tags: operators, expression, vim, operator-precedence

There is a feature in Vim I would find so great.. may I ask if it exists or if anyone had an idea about how I would start implementing it?

'Inspired from Mathematica's front end's `ctrl-.` feature, one would be able to sequentially select, in visual mode, the successive layers of an expression the cursor is taken into. For, example, if we consider the following expression in an imaginary langage:

```
# enter visual mode at this position:
for(i in 1:n){
    a = append(a, b[i %% floor((n + 1) / 2)] + c - n * last(a));
                                        ^
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2                                                                 # selected text after first hit

(n + 1) / 2                                                       # second hit

floor((n + 1) / 2)                                                # third hit

i %% floor((n + 1) / 2)                                           # fourth hit

b[i %% floor((n + 1) / 2)]                                        # fifth hit

b[i %% floor((n + 1) / 2)] + c - n * last(a)                      # sixth hit

append(a, b[i %% floor((n + 1) / 2)] + c - n * last(a))           # seventh hit

a = append(a, b[i %% floor((n + 1) / 2)] + c - n * last(a));      # eight hit

for(i in 1:n){
    a = append(a, b[i %% floor((n + 1) / 2)] + c - n * last(a)); `# etc. until the whole file gets selected
}
```

I am aware this would require the feature to be aware of the various operators in the langage and their respective precedences, but this is not too much of an input, is it?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Vim can't do that by default but there is at least one plugin that does what you want: [vim-expand-region](https://github.com/terryma/vim-expand-region).

Comment: Yeah, 'looks like you just stroke the strike! Thanks! I'm just trying to look now wether or not we can define our own precedences :)

Comment: Glad you've found it; I remembered that one, too! Note that this requires the corresponding text objects to be available (for the various brackets, you can use the built-in ones).

Comment: Okay, I've overlooked it a little bit. If I understand well, vim-expand-region does the trick by using braces and stuff -- which is a *very good* start -- but does not read the text in terms of 'to-be-evaluated' *expressions*. For instance, in `f(a + b/2, c)`, it won't select `2` then `b/2` then `a + b/2` then the whole stuff, it will directly jump to the whole expression because of the parenthesis. Do you get my point? But good start anyway. :) Any more idea?

Comment: There's another one that is based on syntax, by a japanese vimmer IIRC, but I can't find it at the moment.