# Search and retrieve patterns from a list

Tags: regex, list, search, vim

Let's say I have a list of patterns such like `['AB', ')', '%%', '<.*>']`.
I need to search for one of them forward or backward, starting from the cursor position.

Once the first one is found, how do I retrieve its index in the list? I.e, how do I know which one it is?

[EDIT]: the thing is that I actually have two lists of the same size. Once the first match is found in one direction, I'll need to search the *corresponding one* in the other direction.
PLUS, each pattern is associated with a certain *precedence* (its index in the list), which I need to retrieve once it is found.

(The overall idea is to build something that would be able to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002711/how-do-i-sequentially-select-parts-of-an-expression-in-vim), with custom delimiters and operators.)

Comment: That has nothing to do with design patterns, right?

Comment: @JBNizet Hum, I'm quite not sure. Either I don't know what a design pattern is and it has nothing to do with my problem, OR I don't know what a design pattern is and I should because this would be the solution to my problem. In both case I feel like I should ask you.. *what do you mean by 'design pattern'*? :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/design-patterns/info

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. Well I feel like it.. doesn't indeed, or in a very lazy way. I just need to know how I would achieve *this* in vimscript: `'AB'` and `'<.*>'` are just *regex* patterns. ..?

Comment: I have no clue. Know nothing about vim, and saw your question because it was incorrectly tagged with design-patterns.

Comment: @JBNizet Oh, was it?! Sorry for that, I might have done something wrong :\ I meant *regex* patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it: the `searchpos` function with the `'p'` flag allows you to retrieve the position and the id of the match in for a compound pattern, see `:help searchpos`.